# License error manager-4

Tags: matlab

How to resolve this error? Whenever i am using 'syms' it shows this error:-

"Error using sym
License checkout failed.
License Manager Error -4
Maximum number of users for Symbolic_Toolbox reached.
Try again later.
To see a list of current users use the lmstat utility or contact your License
Administrator.

Troubleshoot this issue by visiting:
http://www.mathworks.com/support/lme/R2013b/4

Diagnostic Information:
Feature: Symbolic_Toolbox
License path:
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2013b_licenses;C:\MATLAB\licenses\license.dat;C:\MATLAB\licenses\network.lic
Licensing error: -4,132." 
Any solution?

Comment: Let me guess. You are in an university/education center where Matlab is isntalled in the net, however, you runiversity doesnt own a full education license of Matlab, and just buys individual licenses of toolboxes. Therefore, there are limited licenses. There are another 4 students around uni that are using that toolbox, so you cant. Just wait for them to finish ;)

Answer (score 2):

It means that you are using a concurrent (network) license of MATLAB, presumably on a university campus, and your license includes a number of "seats" of MATLAB and its associated toolboxes, which allow up to `N` people on the network using MATLAB concurrently, and say `M` people (generally `M<N`) using the Symbolic Toolbox. When you are user number `N+1` for MATLAB, or `M+1` for the Symbolic Toolbox, you will get that error message. Not much to do other than wait for somebody to log out and stop using MATLAB/Symbolic Toolbox (or ask your university to purchase more seats...)

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is only for the license of "Symbolic_Toolbox" then you can implement the following lines in your matlab script:

```
% Wait until license is available
while (~license('checkout','Symbolic_Toolbox'))
    pause(1);
end
```

It waits until one license is available and take it for you, then continue with the instructions of your code. You can do the same for all the toolboxes, just change "Symbolic_Toolbox" for the corresponding one.

On the other hand, if the problem is with the number of "seats" for MATLAB (am304), then you are supposed to check if there is one "seat" available before executing (sending) your matlab script to the cluster, but I don't know the way to do that.

Warning:The name of the toolboxes that you get when your tap 'ver' in the command window of matlab is not the same as the one you will use in your code. To get these names follow this : http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97495-how-can-i-test-the-license-for-a-toolbox-in-matlab